# Multi Threading and graphics

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, repaint

My project is based on multi threading and graphics. The problem is in calling repaint() method. I am trying to call repaint method from class second which implements runnable and paint() method is in class first extending Canvas. But repaint not working.
What should I do?

Thnx

Comment: Some [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for the problem concern will be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

It would be much wise, that instead of using `Canvas`, if you override the [`paintComponent(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method of a `JComponent` and paint on it, instead of overriding `paint(...)` method.

Comment: Good advice; for reference, "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

The `Component.repaint()` method, under Swing in particular, only marks the component as needing a repaint, it doesn't actually trigger the repaint directly.

Make sure you allow other threads to run by calling `Thread.yield()`, as it's the main graphics thread (which launched your other thread(s)) that actually checks the components to see what needs to be repainted.